# Bundle Apache Karaf Decanter Collector Prometheus in Waiting State

Tags: java, prometheus, bundle, apache-karaf

I'm deploying monitoring solution with Decanter Karaf and i've installed prometheus features: collectors and appenders. And i have java errors
**ERROR | tures-3-thread-1 | PrometheusCollector              | 581 - org.apache.karaf.decanter.collector.prometheus - 2.9.0 | bundle org.apache.karaf.decanter.collector.prometheus:2.9.0 (581)[org.apache.karaf.decanter.collector.prometheus.PrometheusCollector(30)] : The activate method has thrown an exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prometheus.url is mandatory in the configuration** and the bundle org.apache.karaf.decanter.collector.prometheus is always in waiting state.
I added the prometheus url in the cfg file **etc/org.apache.karaf.decanter.collector.prometheus.cfg** but i have always the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/decanter/latest-2/html/#_prometheus) that is the correct configuration.

Based on this little info I can only advise to debug, you might have made a simple configuration mistake.